# When tokenizing credit card information, does it make sense tokenize every credit card attribute in order to be PCI compliant?

Tags: pci-compliance, pci-dss

For example, if credit card has the following attributes:

- First Name
- Last Name
- **Credit Card Number**
- CVV
- Expiration

Is tokenizing *just* the **Credit Card Number** enough to be PCI compliant?

Correspondingly, if tokenizing ACH details and the details include:

- ACH Routing
- ACH Bank Name
- ACH **Account Number**

Is tokenizing *just* the **Account Number** enough to be PCI compliant?

Or, is every attribute required to have its own token such that the number of tokens necessary to be PCI compliant equal to the number of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

ACH is not part of PCI compliance (PCI stands for payment *card* industry) and it has its own set of rules you must follow ([see NACHA compliance](https://www.nacha.org/products/ach-compliance-manual)).

The point of tokenizing is to hide all of the credit card information from everyone except those who need access to it. The token is then used to represent the card in your system.

What you probably mean in *encryption*. Firstly, you shouldn't be storing credit card information and, if you require doing so, you should be using a third party to do so. Many payment gateways and services offer this ability and removes most of the PCI compliance burden, and risk, from you. But if you choose to store this data locally, [PCI outlines](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf) what encryption you may use and what must be encrypted:

- Primary Account Number
- Cardholder Name (if stored with the account number)
- Expiration Date (if stored with the account number)

You also may **not** store CVV numbers under any circumstances.

Comment: Thank you John. I have more information now with your response than I did before I posted the question. I really appreciate your input here and expert insights. Do you happen to have any references that support the idea that not storing CVV under any circumstances?

Comment: The PCI document I link clearly states that on page 2

Comment: Hi @jbooker. If this, or any answer, has solved your question please consider [accepting it](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.